# How can I use quantifiers in a sed substitution expression (indenting text)?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm using `| sed` to indent the result of some command (let's take a plain `$ echo something` for this example). I want to prefix the result with, say, 10 spaces. The following works fine:

```
$ echo something | sed 's/^/         /'
         something
```

But isn't there a way to use quantifiers in the `| sed` expression?

I tried for example

```
$ echo something | sed 's/^/ {10}/'
 {10}something
```

But obviously it doesn't work. `{10}` isn't interpreted as a quantifier.

And protecting the braces with backslashes doesn't work either:

```
$ echo something | sed 's/^/ \{10\}/'
 {10}something
```

Is there a way to use quantifiers in the substitution expression?

Comment: You could use awk instead ... `| awk '{printf "%10s%s\n", "", $0}'`. Know you are asking for sed, so only a comment.

Comment: @ibuprofen : that's a great and short solution, I usually don't think at `awk` when I think "string replacement", but it seems `awk` can sometimes be more convenient than `sed`. Thanks

Comment: Yeah `printf` in general is a powerful tool for formatting. Have a look into it if not familiar with it. It differs some between implementations, i.e. shells, coreutils, c, awk, perl, ... but basics are the same. E.g. also: `awk -v width=10 '{printf "%*s%s\n", width, "", $0}'` (using asterisk in format string to denote width is a variable).

Comment: For this particular case, you could insert a single tab character, then "multiply" it to a desired number of space characters using the `expand` command: `echo 'something' | sed 's/^/\t/' | expand -it 10`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot of good solutions, I especially like @nezabudka's `| pr -T -o10` solution, really short and simple.

Now, for the fun of it, I found a "`sed` only" solution (no `printf`, no `expand`, no nothing) :

```
$ echo something | sed ':L; /^ \{10\}/! {s/^/ /;b L}'
          something
```

**EDIT:** At @Barmar's request, some explanation :

- `:L;` creates a label, named `L` (you could name it anything)
- We append a space at the beginning of the line, with `s/^/ /`. Then we go back to the label (`b L`, we `b`ranch to the label `L`, kind of a `goto`)
- And we make this expression conditional : it's only executed as long as the line doesn't start with 10 spaces (`/^ \{10\}/!`)

So, basically, we repeat "add a space at the beginning of the line" until the line begins with 10 spaces

While @nezabudka's `pr` solution is clearly the easiest way to append spaces in front of a line, this `sed` solution is more versatile. To add for example 5 times `XYZ-` in front of a line :

```
$ echo something | sed ':L; /^\(XYZ-\)\{5\}/! {s/^/XYZ-/;b L}'
XYZ-XYZ-XYZ-XYZ-XYZ-something
```

Comment: Amazing! That's guru level :)

Comment: If your guru is into hacks. ;)  (It's certainly clever...but contrived.)

Comment: @BLayer I was referencing to the sed's manual [Commands for sed gurus](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands) ;-)

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Ah. I know that documentation but didn't remember that section name. Nice obscure reference. ;)

Comment: Could you explain how this works for those of us who aren't `sed` gurus (I've always been of the opinion that anything that requires use of sed's hold space should be done in another language).

Comment: @Barmar : I updated my answer with some explanation

Comment: Note that it's GNU `sed` syntax. In standard syntax, you'd need a `;` before the `}` and can't have anything after the `:` and `b` commands.

Comment: Also note that it won't insert 10 spaces at the start of lines that already start with spaces.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : it will insert spaces, until 10. If the lines starts with 2 spaces, it'll insert 8 more spaces (`echo "  something" | sed ':L; /^ \{10\}/! {s/^/ /;b L}'`)

Answer (score 12):

I don't think it's possible since the replacement in `sed` substitutions isn't a regular expression.

An alternative could be to create a variable and use it as replacement, like this:

```bsh
# use printf to set as many spaces as you want
$ i=$(printf "%10s")

# use the created variable as replacement of the substitution
$ echo something | sed "s/^/$i/"
          something
```

Comment: @steeldriver I was jsut reading the sed manual and was wondering if that would be an option :)

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity : "I don't think it's possible since the replacement in sed substitutions isn't a regular expression". YES, it is possible, without using `printf`. Check my solution below (`echo something | sed ':lbl; /^ \{10\}/! {s/^/ /;b lbl}'`)

Comment: Note that `$(printf "%10s")` really prints a space-padded empty string; an alternate that is closer to the concept of a "quantifier" might be `$(printf " %.0s" $(seq 10))` which could be applied to *any* substring `$(printf "abc%.0s" $(seq 10))`, similar to perl's `x 10` string repetition.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps the `pr` utility will suit you for this purpose:

```bsh
echo $'something\nstuff' | pr -T -o10
          something
          stuff
```

Don't forget about the `-T` option.  That stops `pr` from paginating input and writing headers.

Comment: Great solution too ! Never heard of `pr` before ! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Some of Perl's best stuff was stolen from sed, so the similarities can be useful.
In this case, the perl solution is simpler and perhaps thinking of it in this way may make the sed solution obvious.  What you want is to print 10 spaces *and then* print your output, rather than transforming the line and printing the result.

```perl
echo something | perl -pe 'print " " x 10'
```

The `-p` flag adds an implicit `print $_` to the end of the command.

If you really want to use a regex, use the `/e` flag

```perl
echo something | perl -pe 's/^/" " x 10/e'
```

which runs the substitution as [an executable statement](https://perlmaven.com/regex-superpowers-execute-code-in-substitution) and uses the result as the subbed value. (in this case I get 10  's by using the [repetition operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Multiplicative-Operators), `x` )

Answer (score 2):

You could get your shell to generate the sequence of 10 spaces.

For instance, with `zsh`:

```
$ echo something | sed "s/^/${(l[10])}/"
          something
```

Here using the `l`eft padding parameter expansion flag applied to the empty parameter expansion. You could just as well use the `r`ight one here. To pad with a different character:

```
$ echo something | sed "s/^/${(l[10][.])}/"
..........something
```

Or even sequence of characters:

```
$ echo something | sed "s/^/${(l[10][<>])}/"
<><><><><>something
```

Comment: Doesn't work in bash (bad substitution)

Comment: @ChennyStar, no, as I said, that's for `zsh`, bash has not equivalent, though you could use `printf` there as others have shown.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -pe 's/ ^^ (.*) $$ /{print " " x (10-$0.chars); $0}/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
when
in
the
course
of
human
events
```

Sample Output:

```
  when
    in
   the
course
    of
 human
events
```

Nice coding in Perl from @Boyd led me to this answer, which is a simple way to right-justify lines. The Raku `s///` operator tolerates extraneous spaces on the left (matcher) side, so I've broken out the match elements:  `^^`, `.*`, and `$$`. Of course, the simpler answer to the question is to delete the `-$0.chars` section of the code, so everything is indented 10 spaces (after @Boyd):

```
echo something | raku -pe 'print " " x 10;'
```

For the code presented at the top, clearly you can change the matcher, and it would be fun to specifically match (before? after?) lines starting with proofreader-marks, such as `§` or `¶`. Finally, Raku is advertised to be Unicode-ready, so there *shouldn't* be a worry about mis-alignment (although the test below is extremely limited):

```
raku -pe 's/ ^^ (.*) $$ /{print " " x (4-$0.chars); $0}/;' uni-test.txt
   A
   Á
   Å
   À
   Ä
   B
   ß
   œ
   þ
```

https://www.raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

Another (gnu) sed exclusive solution below:
It is possible using the sed GNU extension "e" command thats allows one to pipe a shell command input directly from sed as this example.

Note that the {1..10} expression: I think it is bash extension not sure it will works with other shells.

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\r" | sed 'e for i in {1..10};do echo -n ".";done'
..........foo 
..........bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an all-sed solution:

```
$ echo something | sed "s/^/$(seq 1 10 | sed 's/.*/ /' | tr -d '\n')/"
          something
```

The outer sed must have double quotes.

Use any character for substitution in the inner sed (and not just blank space):

```
$ echo something | sed "s/^/$(seq 1 10 | sed 's/.*/_/' | tr -d '\n')/"
__________something
```

An even simpler and more flexible way is to have a variable with an arbitrary (say 80) number of spaces and then use this command to chop off as many spaces as you wish for indentation:

```
$ j=$(printf "%80s")
$ echo something | sed "s/^/$(echo "${j:1:12}")/"
            something
```

You can treat j as environment variable and define it only once.